# when scroll to top all my objects have visibility at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, opacity

i have objects (.hideme) which have opacity 0 and when we scroll them to the screen, they become visible. I use jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.hideme').css({'opacity':'0'});

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each(function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
            if(bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){           
                $(this).stop(true).delay(800).animate({'opacity':'1'},600,'easeOutBack');     
            }           
        });   
    });

});
```

The problem is that when i scroll the first .hideme div on the screen, all the other .hideme divs get opacity 1 in the same time, but i would like to make them visible only at the appearence on the screen !
Do you have some idea how to do it ? Thanks in advance.

You can see it here : http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com/demos.html

Comment: You should probably be using offset() not position(), if your reference is the window and not the elements parent. Try with offset and share some feedback if you wish.

Comment: @alou thanks and i would share it with pleasure but i can not write script, only manipulate it sometimes and i never used offset either... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude,

First: you better use css3 transitions to make this animate ease, because if you use `stop()` you will have troubles if the hideme should be visible and the user keep scrolling. You can create a class like:

```
.hideme {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.6s ease;
}
```

Second: you shoud use `offset().top` instead of `position().top`. Learn more about the difference between them.

This is my suggest for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/LEXgX/1/

You better create a function called `visibleHideme();` and execute this function at `$(document).ready()`. As all 'hideme' starts with `opacity:0`, if some 'hideme' should be visible when the page load, the user dont need to scroll the page to make this visible.

```
    function visibleHideme(){
        $('.hideme').each(function(){

            var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
            var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            if(top_of_object > top_of_window && bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){
                $(this).css('opacity','1');
            }
            else {
                $(this).css('opacity','0');
            }

        });
    }
    visibleHideme();
```

And then, when the user scroll the page, will execute the same function.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    visibleHideme();
});
```

Comment: as i saw your fiddle, it is even better than what i had... because originally i was looking for a script to make visible the objects on screen but re-hide them when leave the screen, and what you show me is just the same !!! I will try to do what you suggest and come back later ! Thanks a lot

Comment: just another thing, is it possible to put in settings if i would like that the .hideme objects appear/disappear when they are hald left from the screen ? It is just a detail but would be nicer, because my objects are quiet long so sometimes only one remains on the screen and the upper and lower part of my screen are quiet empty... but if it is difficult, do not worry about it !

Comment: Oh, God, this is heaven ! thanks a lot, i will integrate it tomorrow ! :) I voted this answer too !

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, you need to click on the 'check' left side of my answer until it turns green.

Comment: i clicked on the arrow to up, i clicked on the arrow of your comment about the 2nd fiddle too, i did not know that we can click on the check as well (i find a bit complicated this website, must be here a lot to learn everything), i did it for you !!! Thanks again

Comment: Hello again ! Sorry to continue this subject but this effect is just nice and useful, i would like to use it in another website too. My problem is that now, the elements with above scroll effect are on the home page, they work well but i can not make the same effect at page load. I asked the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346609/elements-with-scroll-to-top-effect-on-home-page  if you can answer, please help me there.