# Elements with "scroll to top" effect on home page

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, opacity

I have elements which appear/disappear at the edge of the screen when scrolled (hideme). I can animate them but the problem is the beginning, at page load. I can not do the same effect at page load... if someone can help how to do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').hide();
  $('.avatar').css('opacity', 0);
  $('.avatar img').css('width', '0vw', 'height', '0vw', 'margin-left', '50%', 'margin-top', '50%');
  $('.intro').css('opacity', 0, 'margin-top', '20%');
  $('.signature').css('opacity', 0, 'top', '75%');

  //calling jPreLoader
  $('body').jpreLoader({
    showSplash: false,
    showPercentage: true,
    loaderVPos: '10%',
    autoClose: true,
  }, function() { //callback function
    $('body').fadeIn(50);
  });

  // scroll effect
  function visibleHideme() {

    $('#home').each(function() {

      var half_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight() / 4);
      var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      if (half_of_object < top_of_window) {
        $('.avatar').delay(700).css({
          'opacity': '0'
        });
        $('.avatar img').delay(800).css({
          'margin-top': '50%',
          'margin-left': '50%',
          'width': '0vw',
          'height': '0vw'
        });
        $('.intro').css({
          'opacity': '0',
          'margin-top': '20%'
        });
        $('.signature').delay(1000).css({
          'opacity': '0',
          'top': '75%'
        });
      }
      if (half_of_object > bottom_of_window) {
        $('.avatar').delay(700).css({
          'opacity': '0'
        });
        $('.avatar img').delay(800).css({
          'margin-top': '50%',
          'margin-left': '50%',
          'width': '0vw',
          'height': '0vw'
        });
        $('.intro').css({
          'opacity': '0',
          'margin-top': '20%'
        });
        $('.signature').delay(1000).css({
          'opacity': '0',
          'top': '75%'
        });
      } else if (half_of_object > top_of_window && half_of_object < bottom_of_window) {
        $('.avatar').delay(700).css({
          'opacity': '1'
        });
        $('.avatar img').delay(800).css({
          'margin-top': '0%',
          'margin-left': '0%',
          'width': '25vw',
          'height': '25vw'
        });
        $('.intro').css({
          'opacity': '1',
          'margin-top': '5%'
        });
        $('.signature').delay(1000).css({
          'opacity': '1',
          'top': '60%'
        });
      }
    });
  }
  visibleHideme();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    visibleHideme();
  });

});
```

```css
#home {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#home .intro {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  width: 65%;
  text-align: left;
}

#home .avatar {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7%;
  top: 35%;
  width: 350px;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 350px;
  height: 25vw;
}

#home .avatar img {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  width: 0vw;
  height: 0px;
  height: 0vw;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 50%;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#home .signature {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  top: 75%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 124px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" id="home">
  <div class="avatar"><img src="uploads/avatar2.jpg" alt="IL Avatar" /></div>
  <img class="signature" src="uploads/signature.png" alt="Sign" />
  <div class="intro">This is a text...</div>
</div>
```

In above case, the page loads with a normal opacity animation, the elements do not do what they do at scrolling at screen edge.

If i add callback function animation (just after the "body" fade in), the elements appear first with normal opacity animation, then they do the animation... i am talking about the following additional codes :

```
$('.avatar').animate({'opacity':1}, 600, 'easeInCirc');
$('.avatar img').delay(100).animate({'width':'25vw','height':'25vw','margin-left':'0%','margin-top':'0%'}, 700, 'easeOutBounce');
$('.intro').delay(500).animate({'opacity':1,'margin-top':'5%'}, 600, 'easeInCirc');
$('.signature').delay(800).animate({'opacity':1,'top':'60%'}, 800, 'easeInCirc');
```

On live here : http://photography.igorlaszlo.com/test2.html
If someone can help me...

Comment: trying to understand the flow of ur program...your dom gets loaded...calls `visibleHideMe` - which handles all the css stuff you want to do...in your question you say you want to do that stuff when the page loads...and you are calling the function in the `$(document).ready` function...im a little confused

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with `$('.avatar').animate({'opacity':1}, 600, 'easeInCirc');
    $('.avatar img').delay(100).animate({'width':'25vw','height':'25vw','margin-left':'0%','margin-top':'0%'}, 700, 'easeOutBounce');
    $('.intro').delay(500).animate({'opacity':1,'margin-top':'5%'}, 600, 'easeInCirc');
    $('.signature').delay(800).animate({'opacity':1,'top':'60%'}, 800, 'easeInCirc');` and where is it?

Comment: @ewizard thanks for your reply ! when i scroll the avatar, text and signature img, they appear with an effect. the avatar gets bigger with an easeOutBounce effect, the text appears from down, the signature the same like the text but later. 
I could do the same effects separately. i can do it when the page load and i can do it when i scroll but not both. **I would like that they make those effects at page load and when i scroll, they disappear the same way and when i scroll the home page again, they appear the same way...**

Comment: ok - so what happens now? you call the `visibleHideMe` function on page load (when the dom is loaded) - what happens? what doesnt work about doing that?

Comment: so - when you say "scroll the home page again" - do you mean that you have navigated away from the page - and are just returning to it?

Comment: sorry for my English, i do not understand "dom" is loaded... what is dom ?

Comment: it is this part `$(document).ready(function() {` everything in there happens when the page loads

Comment: so you have the `visibileHideMe` function in there - and u call it - so it should get executed when the page loads...it is a different thing if you are navigating away from the page, and then coming back to it - because the dom probably isnt reloading...to do that you must use `location.reload()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: what do you make when you visit the website ? first it loads (loading the hideme elements as well as they are visible because they are at the home page), then you look at the other parts of the website, so the elements disappear (with the same effects), then you come back maybe to the home page, so when you scroll there, those hideme elements will be appeared again with the effect...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56043/discussion-between-ewizard-and-igor-laszlo).

Comment: so, do you say that first i can use my codes (the last codes i gave) at document ready, then i can use the visiblehideme at reload function ? Which means that i must add reload function before the visiblehideme codes ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the live link you've provided and assume you want no avatar/text/signature shown when page loads but have it fade in, similar to the effect when I scroll back to top after scrolling down far enough for them to vanish.

I'd start edit your css files and therefore initial styling to match the final animation state when the elements are hidden:
*Edit: Which is actually true*

Then call the code to show them when your document is ready:
*Edit: Which s actually done by calling `visibleHideMe();`*

Edit: However, there is a pre-loader rocking around and now I would say there's a timing problem. So remove the call to `visibleHideMe();` from document.ready and rather add it to jPreLoader's callback:

```
//calling jPreLoader
$('body').jpreLoader({
    showSplash: false,
    showPercentage: true,
    loaderVPos: '10%',
    autoClose: true,        
}, function() { //callback function
    $('body').fadeIn(50, visibileHideMe); //callback after body finished fading
    $('#menu-bttn span').text('Show Menu');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Yoshi... somehow the problem and confusion came from the end of my codes `visibleHideme(); $(window).scroll(function(){visibleHideme();});`... i deleted it from the end and i put all hideme codes in the scroll function... also, i added the callback codes for the beginning to have the effect after body fade in. 
Thanks for your interest again !

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! \^^/ Don't forget to accept an answer as you please so this question does not remain marked as unanswered :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, so i am affraid to manipulate the jquery codes but somehow the answer is quiet logical...

Finally i must use the codes i gave lastly, they will give the "start" effect :

```
...}, function() {  //callback function
    $('body').fadeIn(50);
    $('#menu-bttn span').text('Show Menu');
    $('.avatar').animate({'opacity':1}, 600, 'easeInCirc');
    $('.avatar img').delay(500).animate({'width':'25vw','height':'25vw','margin-left':'0%','margin-top':'0%'}, 700, 'easeOutBounce');
    $('.intro').delay(500).animate({'opacity':1,'margin-top':'5%'}, 600, 'easeInCirc');
    $('.signature').delay(800).animate({'opacity':1,'top':'60%'}, 800, 'easeInCirc');
});
```

Then i just had to reorganize my visibleHideme and simplefy... i just deleted the        visibleHideme(); from the end of the code and i put the rest in the scroll function :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#home').each(function(){             
        //var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
        //var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var half_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight()/4);
        var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();              
        if(half_of_object < top_of_window) {
            $('.avatar').delay(700).css({'opacity':'0'});
            $('.avatar img').delay(800).css({'margin-top':'50%','margin-left':'50%','width':'0vw','height':'0vw'});
            $('.intro').css({'opacity':'0','margin-top':'20%'});
            $('.signature').delay(1000).css({'opacity':'0','top':'75%'});
        }
        if (half_of_object > bottom_of_window){
            $('.avatar').delay(700).css({'opacity':'0'});
            $('.avatar img').delay(800).css({'margin-top':'50%','margin-left':'50%','width':'0vw','height':'0vw'});
            $('.intro').css({'opacity':'0','margin-top':'20%'});
            $('.signature').delay(1000).css({'opacity':'0','top':'75%'});
        }               
        else if(half_of_object > top_of_window && half_of_object < bottom_of_window){
            $('.avatar').delay(700).css({'opacity':'1'});
            $('.avatar img').delay(800).css({'margin-top':'0%','margin-left':'0%','width':'25vw','height':'25vw'});
            $('.intro').css({'opacity':'1','margin-top':'5%'});
            $('.signature').delay(1000).css({'opacity':'1','top':'60%'});
        }
    });
});
```

So now, i have the same effect at the opening of the website, just like at scrolling...